# Specifying images for top, bottom, left and right. How to do?

Tags: css

I can specify CSS like this:

```
background: #CFCFCF url(button.bmp) repeat-x top;
```

but if I want an image for top along with images for left, right and bottom, how would I go about that?

Comment: You can only specify one background image for an element

Answer (score 3):

You would need to nest some elements to show one image each. As Wayne says, you can only specify one background image for an element (Until [CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) is supported in more browsers).

```
<div id="top">
   <div id="container">
       Put your content here
   </div>
   <div id="right"></div>
   <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Then apply the CSS to each element

```
#top {background: url(top.jpg) no-repeat;}
#container {background: url(left.jpg) no-repeat;}
#right {background: url(right.jpg) no-repeat;}
#bottom {background: url(bottom.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

And you would also need to position the elements properly...

Answer (score -1):

**The HTML**

```
<div class="nice">... inner HTML goes here...</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.nice {
  border: 1px solid #ffcf86;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: url(i5.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.nice:before, .nice:after {
  display: block;
  height: 41px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.nice:before {
  content: url(i1.gif);
  background: url(i2.gif) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

.nice:after {
  content: url(i3.gif);
  background: url(i4.gif) no-repeat 100% 0;
}
```

result:

http: //dense13.com/blogExamples/multiple-background-images-with-css2/desiredResult.gif

Source http: //dense13.com/blog/2008/08/31/multiple-background-images-with-css2/

Old version:

It appears you can do something along the terms of (spaced the property values so that your get the effect):

```
#some_id {
    background-image:    url('image_url'), url('another_image_url');
    background-position: top left,         top right;
}
```

Source [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multiple_backgrounds.html), This works in Safari only (*and I got down-voted about it*).